# icons are characters and not icons in icon font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've made plenty of custom webfonts and icon fonts before and I have no idea why this isn't working. I am sure it is some oversight on my part. I'm using syntax I have used before, generated the webfont two different ways, but both ways and on jsfiddle, my own server, and local machine, the icon isn't rendered and instead the letter, "J". I even installed the font and when I type in it, it renders as the icon.

Here is the css:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'AE Team Icons';
    src:url('http://the-irf.com/files/public/aeteamicons-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('http://the-irf.com/files/public/aeteamicons-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
   unicode-range:U+00-FFFF;
}
i{ font-size:64px; font-family:'AE Team Icons'; }
```

And here is a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5dnay9bh/

Comment: is there anything in inspect element/firebug? my guess is the src file isn't loading.

Comment: @Dylan It isn't loading, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. The path is right. No errors. Not even a request. It is like it is ignoring it.

Comment: i was able to get it to show up in the network tab by downloading it locally but there still seems to be some issue